# Could not instantiate the executor. Make sure a planner module is on the classpath

Tags: scala, apache-flink

For a scala project I use the StreamTableEnvironment and when running my code in IntelliJ everything works fine. However when I try to export my project to a jar (I create a fat jar using sbt assembly), no suitable table factory can be found. I've looked inside the jar and the classes it needs are included. Here the complete stacktrace:

````
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Could not instantiate the executor. Make sure a planner module is on the classpath
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.scala.internal.StreamTableEnvironmentImpl$.lookupExecutor(StreamTableEnvironmentImpl.scala:328)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.scala.internal.StreamTableEnvironmentImpl$.create(StreamTableEnvironmentImpl.scala:284)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.scala.StreamTableEnvironment$.create(StreamTableEnvironment.scala:366)
        at org.tudelft.plugins.SQLService$.setupEnv(SQLService.scala:40)
        at org.tudelft.plugins.SQLStage.main(SQLStage.scala:19)
        at org.codefeedr.stages.OutputStage.transform(OutputStage.scala:45)
        at org.codefeedr.pipeline.Pipeline.$anonfun$startMock$1(Pipeline.scala:240)
        at org.codefeedr.pipeline.Pipeline.$anonfun$startMock$1$adapted(Pipeline.scala:238)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
        at org.codefeedr.pipeline.Pipeline.startMock(Pipeline.scala:238)
        at org.tudelft.Main$.main(Main.scala:34)
        at org.tudelft.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.NoMatchingTableFactoryException: Could not find a suitable table factory for 'org.apache.flink.table.delegation.ExecutorFactory' in
the classpath.

Reason: No factory implements 'org.apache.flink.table.delegation.ExecutorFactory'.

The following properties are requested:
class-name=org.apache.flink.table.executor.StreamExecutorFactory
streaming-mode=true

The following factories have been considered:

        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService.filterByFactoryClass(TableFactoryService.java:243)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService.filter(TableFactoryService.java:186)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService.findAllInternal(TableFactoryService.java:172)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactoryService.findAll(TableFactoryService.java:126)
        at org.apache.flink.table.factories.ComponentFactoryService.find(ComponentFactoryService.java:48)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.scala.internal.StreamTableEnvironmentImpl$.lookupExecutor(StreamTableEnvironmentImpl.scala:312)
        ... 16 more```
````

Comment: Can You provide the dependencies for You project please ??

Answer (score 4):

Similar but slightly different to what OP needed: I have unit tests using the Table API that were failing with the same error message, even though the same pipeline worked fine when submitted to a real flink cluster.

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Could not instantiate the executor. Make sure a planner module is on the classpath
```

The solution was to add:

```
<dependency>
    <!-- this is needed to use the Table API from unit tests -->
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table-planner_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I believe flink-table-planner-blink is no longer available in recent versions (I'm using 1.15), and has instead replaced flink-table-planner.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late to answer, but I had the same issue and the solution was to add the blink planner dependency (original answer here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14031)

Answer (score 1):

It's useful for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table-planner-blink_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
```